# Draggable = false link in lightning-out - aura components

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

When I set a link to draggable = false in aura component (using lightning-out), the attribute is somehow being reset to draggable = true during compilation. The link is draggable.

Why is the attribute being set to true and how can I make an undraggable link in aura components.

Component code:

```
<aura:component>
  test
  <a draggable="false" href="https://www.google.com">my link</a>
</aura:component>
```

Aura app:

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="test"/>
</aura:application>
```

VF page:

```
 <apex:page cache="false" sidebar="false">
 <apex:includeLightning />
 <div id="test-area">


 </div>
 <script>

    $Lightning.use("c:testApp", function(){
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:test",
        {},
        "test-area"
        )
    });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why this is happening, but the work around I'm currently using is to set the anchor elements to draggable=false using javascript with a render handler.

in cmp:

```
 <aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{! c.onRender }" />
```

in controller:

```
onRender : function(component, event, helper) {
   var anchorList =  document.getElementsByTagName('a');
   for(var i = 0; i < anchorList.length; i ++){
      anchorList[i].setAttribute("draggable", "false");
   }
```

Seems to work, but feels like there should be a better way of doing this!